# Python - Scrapy unable to fetch data

Tags: python, scrapy, scraper

I am just starting out with Python/Scrapy.

I have a written a spider that crawls a website and fetches information. But i am stuck in 2 places.

1. I am trying to retrieve the telephone numbers from a page and they are coded like this

   ```
   <span class="mrgn_right5">(+001) 44 42676000,</span>
   <span class="mrgn_right5">(+011) 44 42144100</span>
   ```

The code i have is:

```
getdata = soup.find(attrs={"class":"mrgn_right5"})
if getdata:
   aditem['Phone']=getdata.get_text().strip()
   #print phone
```

But it is fetching only the first set of numbers and not the second one. How can i fix this?

1. On the same page there is another set of information

I am using this code

```
    getdata = soup.find(attrs={"itemprop":"pricerange"})
    if getdata:
        #print getdata
        aditem['Pricerange']=getdata.get_text().strip()
        #print pricerange
```

But it is not fetching any thing.

Any help on fixing these two would be great.

Comment: If you're using scrapy, then it should be possible to use scrapy's in-built HTML selector to scrape the required information.

Comment: @Talvalin, My knowledge of python/scrapy is very very limited. I have just started learning recently.

Comment: Sure. My answer below fixes your first issue, but I can't test the code for your second issue without some example html. Could you provide some please?

Comment: When you get a chance (ie after these issues have been fixed), take a look here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: @Talvalin, Here is an example page from the site http://bit.ly/1jResAq

How do i modify the find to find_all? is it just replacing the find with find_all? i Tried and that does not work.. Throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a browse of the [Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), `find` will only return a single result. If multiple results are expected/required, then use `find_all` instead. Since there are two results, a list will be returned, so the elements of the list need to be joined together (for example) to add them to `Phone` field of your `AdItem`.

```
getdata = soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"mrgn_right5"})
if getdata:
   aditem['Phone'] = ''.join([x.get_text().strip() for x in getdata])
```

For the second issue, you need to access the attributes of the returned object. Try the following:

```
getdata = soup.find(attrs={"itemprop":"pricerange"})
if getdata:
    aditem['Pricerange'] = getdata.attrs['content']
```

And for the address information, the following code works but is very hacky and could no doubt be improved by someone who understands Beautiful Soup better than me.

```
getdata = soup.find(attrs={"itemprop":"address"})
address = getdata.span.get_text()
addressLocality = getdata.meta.attrs['content']
addressRegion = getdata.find(attrs={"itemprop":"addressRegion"}).attrs['content']
postalCode = getdata.find(attrs={"itemprop":"postalCode"}).attrs['content']
```

Comment: I just modified the code as

getdata = soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"mrgn_right5"})
if getdata:
   aditem['Phone']=getdata.get_text().strip()
   #print phone

But it gives an error.
i prefer to give out the link in private.

Comment: When i do the find_all this is the error that i am getting

exceptions.AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: I've edited my answer above to include a fix for your second issue

Comment: Thank you. The price range works great. But for the phone number i am getting an error "exceptions.AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: My mistake. The code for the phone number should use `find_all` not `find`. I've updated the code for completeness.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate all this help.

One more place where i am stuck is the address part... 

How can i fetch the address part like this?
streetAddress, addressLocality, addressRegion - postalCode

These are all given in schema tags on the same page above.

Comment: `soup.find(attrs={"itemprop":"address"})` will get that entire address span. If you need further assistance at that point, then I would strongly recommend using the Beautiful Soup documentation, and testing out various searches in a Python interpreter. It's basically what I've been doing, and it's a good learning experience

Comment: I've added some code to retrieve address information as requested. If this code is useful to you, then please remember to upvote and accept this answer. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been going through the docs and i was able to get the information. But where i am stuck (once again) is how to get them all in one field that i can export.

Like combine the addressLocality, addressRegion and postalCode into one.

Comment: At this point I would strongly recommend working through a Python tutorial such as Learn Python the Hard Way, as basic string manipulation is fundamental and should be at least reviewed if not outright learned prior to dabbling in web scrapers.